# Pandas Rolling Window : Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

Trying to use the following to get the mean of a rolling window over pandas :

```
df['my_variable'] = df \
        .groupby('another_variable') \
        .rolling(window=window_val, min_periods=1)['my_variable'] \
        .mean() \
        .reset_index(drop=True) \
        .values
```

this piece of code works perfectly fine on my local system [mac], but when i try to run the same on an armv71 system I constantly run into the following :

```
Exception Type:  Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pipeline_Code_3.7.py", line 272, in <module>
    .rolling(window=window_val, min_periods=1)['my_variable'] \
```

I have tried the following :

1. typecasting to int64 like so

   ```
   df['my_variable'] = df \
               .groupby('another_variable') \
               .rolling(window=window_val, min_periods=1)['my_variable'] \
               .mean() \
               .reset_index(drop=True) \
               .values.astype('int64')
   ```
2. checking if the column has any null values and eliminating them, not sure if this helps but was making sure

I assume this a system specific problem, I am not familiar with armv71 because I have not faced this before.

Comment: armv7l is 32 bit processor. You should typecast all the data to 32 bits and not the other way around.

Comment: thanks for your response Xbel. This makes sense, I actually have few values that are large and typecasting them to 32 leads to an overflow error. Any advice on how to deal with this ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean that the numbers are too large. More than 2.000.000.000? Do you really need that precision?

Comment: I realized I did have a really large number [14 digits] which I removed now. Post this I am now hitting the same error again as mentioned in the question, even without the astype('int64')

Comment: Trying int32 now

Comment: All my columns are now in int32, I still face the same error. Could it be because I have a column timestamp that is of datatype timestamp64[ns] ?